# How to easily theme one option of a choice form field in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I'm currently using a choice field (with the option "expanded" set to true) to display a list of radio buttons to select a value. I'd like to change the way it is rendered by `$view['form']->widget()` and already have another global template in `src/MyProject/ABundle/Resources/views/Form/choice_widget.html.php` which can not be changed.

How do I specify a new template for the radio buttons in a php view (no twig)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While coming back, here is how it can easily be done but the symfony official doc is not clear.

Put your `choice_widget.html.php` in `src/YourProject/YourBundle/Resources/view/Something/` then when you need a radio button themed with it, use:

```
<?php $view['form']->setTheme($form, array('YourProjectYourBundle:Something')) ?>
<?php echo $view['form']->widget($form) ?>
```

With $form being your form view.